# ElasticSearch Availability / Partition Tolerance with 3 Nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I'm new to ElasticSearch and try to figure out proper Setup for a 3 Node Cluster that should tolerate the loss of 2 Nodes.

From what I understand, setup would be:

- DC1: 2 nodes
- DC2: 1 node
- shards: 3
- replicas: 2
- minimum_master_nodes: 1

Is it correct that without setting minimum_master_nodes to 1, if DC1 goes down, the remaining node in DC2 would not be able to reply?

My product I'm installing says it does not recommend to set minimum_master_nodes to anything else than quorum.

I would like to understand the possible side effects of setting minimum_master_nodes to 1. Or is there another way to tolerate the loss of 2 Nodes in a 3 Node Cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have 2 nodes loss tolerance on 3 nodes cluster.

You will have to put minimum_master_nodes: 1, but imagine all nodes are lost connection to each other and they all became masters which will bring you to "split brain" situation and data written to one node will not go to other nodes.

To achieve 2 nodes loss tolerance you will need at least 5 nodes, and 2 replica per index. Number of shards is not important in this case, but you can change it to have better load balancing.

Formula to calculate number on node needed:

```
total_nodes - lost_nodes > total_nodes/2
where total_nodes >0; lost_nodes >= 0; total_nodes > lost_nodes
```

in other words you should always have more than 50% nodes alive to operate the cluster. If you allow 50% or less split brain situation became possible.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I was basing the assumption of beeing able to tolerate the loss of 2 nodes in a 3 nodes cluster on this [article](https://cpratt.co/how-many-shards-should-elasticsearch-indexes-have/) which gives the impression that this would be possible.  So from what you are saying then in a 3 nodes cluster having 2 replicas doesn't make much sense?

Comment: Another question: if I follow the recommendation and configure minimum_master_nodes to quorum, but still configure replicas: 2, would then in the case of a 2 nodes loss the remaining node block read and write requests, or would it be able to serve at least read requests? Then it would still make much sense to configure replicas: 2. In my case 3 nodes setup is given and trying to optimize configuration. The client application of ElasticSearch will mostly read, updates to the index are not more than once a day.

Comment: Having (number of replicas + primary index) equal to number of nodes will guaranty you have full index on every node. Which is beneficial in your case with mostly read queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just found the answer to my question. The single surviving node can serve read requests even if minimum_master_nodes is set to quorum. This can be controlled with the setting no_master_block, which controls the operations that are blocked when there is no active master. It takes values 'all' or 'write' (default). Means with default setting the single surviving node will be able to serve read requests, if replicas is set to 2.